# Should logic changing the URL based on the state of a model be in the controller or the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm using Rails 4.2 with [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) to create a state machine for an item. The item can transition between different states (`created`, `onboarded`, `checked_out`, etc.), and I want to create a page where the action url changes depending on the state of the item. So for example, if it's been `created` already, the action might be to `onboard` it.

From a design perspective, I can either put a function on the model itself like `next_step_path`, which would return the correct URL based on the state, and using Rails helpers like `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the model. Or I could have that logic in the controller, where I generate the URL based on the state of the model.

Is there a common design pattern for this? I originally wrote it into the model, but I'm now leaning towards the controller since I need to generate both the URL and the display based off of it.

Comment: My approach would be to utilize the state in the model in a specific helper function that generates the url. Then call the function in the controller. But I'm open to hearing better methods.

Comment: the model should not know anything about urls. a helper method would make sense. Or the controller if that works. Or make a new class to do it that's neither the ActiveRecord model nor the controller, and call it from the controller and/or a helper method.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is probably a presenter. Don't think it should be in a helper as it's model specific. Presenters wrap models to provide view related attributes.

```
class ItemPresenter
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def next_step_path
  end

  def method_missing(method)
    @object.send(method)
  end
end
```

http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/09/26/presenting-the-rails-presenter-pattern/